# How to save variable as a string in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to save a string with number and math operator into database. I want to save the face value of string, but php or mysql is calculating the string and then saving it to the database.

For example:

```
$stringValue = "24/2";
$query = "UPDATE winter";
$query .= " SET value =".$stringValue;
$query .= " WHERE name = 'xyz'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

After running the code, I want the value saved in database to be "24/2", but it is being saved as 12.

Comment: It's mysql, because your query is `...SET value = 24/2...`; try adding single quotes around it; or better yet, use parameterized queries to avoid "sql injection" vulnerabilities. _(Edit: and by "it" I mean around the string value in the query.)_

Comment: `"but it is being saved as 12"` - Because `24/2` *is* 12.  Maybe you meant `'24/2'` as a *string*?

Comment: Uueerdo solution worked. I added quotes. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Uueerdo said you need to add `'` sign before and after string in `SQL`.

```
$stringValue = "24/2";
$query = "UPDATE winter";
$query .= " SET value ='".$stringValue."'";
$query .= " WHERE name = 'xyz'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Also you probably should use prepared statements (not much longer, but more safer).

```
$stringValue = "24/2";
$name = "xyz";
$query = "UPDATE winter";
$query .= " SET value=?";
$query .= " WHERE name=?";

$stmt = $connection->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bind_param( 'ss', $stringValue, $name );
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
```

Comment: Note: even when _you_ are the one generating the data, it's worth preventing sql injection since you _can_ unintentionally sql-inject yourself. Rule of thumb: never trust any input.